# Insert image in android and for all screen sizes

Tags: android, xml, image, screen

I want to add a image for my android app.
I want to add image like this

`ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="321dp"
        android:src="@drawable/welcome"`

it need to cover full width ow screen and it height need to be 1/3 screen (i need to add few button bellow this image)
but when i simulate it i did't get my expectation.It will show middle of screen and it does't apply to full width

How can i solve this problem 
Thank you

Comment: BETTER use layout weights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that the image you're using is a 9-patch image. That'll get the thing done. When making a 9-patch image make sure you're enabling it to stretch horizontally.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you friends
I tried something like this
I got my results

`ImageView

        android:id="@+id/imageView1"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="@drawable/welcome"`

Thank you